# Looping audio in Phaser

Tags: javascript, audio, phaser-framework

I've just started making a simple platformer with Phaser, I'm new to this.

I have managed to get music playing but cant get it to loop and Google hasn't helped.

Heres the audio code I'm using, any advice?

```
game.load.audio('hotttt', ['assets/audio/hotttt.mp3', 'assets/audio/hotttt.ogg']);

music = game.add.audio('hotttt');

music.play();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to create a new `Phaser.Sound` object and enable `loop`.

```
game.load.audio('hotttt', ['assets/audio/hotttt.mp3', 'assets/audio/hotttt.ogg']);

// *true* param enables looping
music = new Phaser.Sound(game,'hotttt',1,true);

music.play();
```

You can refer to the documentation - [Phaser.Sound](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Sound.html)

Comment: That doesn't seem to load any audio for me :(

Comment: Try delaying `music.play()` with setTimeout().

Comment: Still no luck                                                                                          "music = new Phaser.Sound(game,'hotttt',1,true);
    setTimeout(function(){ music.play(); }, 1000);"

Answer (score 10):

First, you load the audio file like you did, and then create the instance for the audio itselfs.

Example:

```
game.load.audio('background_music', ['assets/sounds/background_music.mp3', 'assets/sounds/background_music.wav']);

backgroundMusic = game.add.audio('background_music');
backgroundMusic.loop = true; // This is what you are looking for
backgroundMusic.play();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: for me the loop works in firefox but not in chrome. and no sound when cordova builds for android :(

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.GameObjectFactory.html) for v2.4.4 (and I tested it with 2.6.1) you can pass an extra argument to the `game.add.audio()` function for looping

Example

```
game.load.audio('background', ['assets/audio/background.wav'])

const backgroundSound = game.add.audio('background', 0.5, true) // here "true" means to loop

backgroundSound.play()
```

That worked fine for me

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that works for me is this:

```
music = game.add.audio('yourMusicFile');
music.loopFull()
```

Comment: Nice bump! Thx will try this and let you know how I get on

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who is looking at this thread for Phaser 3.

Load music in preload()

`this.load.audio('musicaudio', 'assets/musicl.mp3');`

Then in your own function or create()

```
var music = this.sound.add('musicaudio');
music.setLoop(true);
music.play();
```

I don't quite understand yet the mechanics behind initializing audio but in order do so in my Chrome environment I had to set this in the initial config declaration.

```
audio: {
        disableWebAudio: true,
        noAudio: false
    },
```

P.S. I read somewhere that you shouldn't use mp3's for looping but it works fine for me. Perhaps there is a brief pause.